# Apache SSL with LetsEncrypt messes up redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, httpd, httpd.conf, lets-encrypt

I have just setup `letsencrypt` on my CentOS 6 server running apache and the SSL all works fine. I've just tried to redirect `http` to `https` using this:

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

But, in the case of going to: `http://example.com/somepath`, instead of getting `https://example.com/somepath` I get `https://example.comesomepath`...

For some reason, the `/` isn't added to the path that I'm accessing and I can't see how I can fix this issue.

My `httpd.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
# RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 # tried using this too, no luck
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Running: `Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`

Comment: everything is fine as shown in your config.Why are u adding " RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1" ? clear browser cache and test.

Comment: @SachinSingh The RedirectMatch is likely so visiting directly `http://example.com/something` doesn't lose your place by redirecting to `https://example.com/` without the `/something`.

Comment: So I edited `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` and added a `ServerName` as well as `DocumentRoot` on it, inside the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` block and it seems to have fixed the issue...